# How to see this implication of infinity sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I see the following implication in one paper:

If I know

For $i = 1,...n$
1. $\underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim inf}}\ \ \|y(k)-x_i(k)\|= 0$ with probability $1$.
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n \|y(k)-x_i(k)\|^2$ converges with probability $1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Then, these imply $\forall i$,

> $$\underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim}}\ \ \|y(k)-x_i(k)\|= 0 \ \ \text{with probability 1}$$

**My question is how to get this result? (similar theorem or lemma?)**

The 2. only says the sum converges (without saying that it converges to $0$)

Answer (score 0):

This is in general wrong. Simply choose $y \equiv 0$, $n = 2$ and $x_i(k) = (-1)^{i + k} + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of the sum
implies that the 
*terms* go to zero,
not that the *sum* goes to zero.

Comment: But now the sum has finite terms (in 2.), n. Should each term go to zero?